# using ImageLoader download Images from AWS url android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, universal-image-loader

the purpose: Trying to show images that store in AWS. When pull up/down 12 images will show in GridView. I could download the images by using:

```
      try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(mIcon11);
```

This means the url works. However, the question is when I passing the url to the Image Loader, it show the error below: (I replace the key and other stuff in the url to 'something'.)

```
05-13 10:29:40.437  14053-14160/com.example.test E/ImageLoader﹕ https://s3.amazonaws.com/test/photo/1405.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=something& something = something&Signature= something
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://s3.amazonaws.com/test/photo/1405.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=something& something = something&Signature= something
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:122)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:86)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.getImageStream(BaseImageDecoder.java:93)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:73)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:264)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:237)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:135)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

How could I download the aws url with Image Loader? Or is there any other better way to showing 12 or more images from aws? Anyone know? Thank you so much!

Comment: do you mind to use library for dowloading?

Comment: That error above is caused by file not found.

Comment: @NikMyers do you have any suggestion library ?

Comment: @inmyth yes, since I could use the same url download image by using InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in); I really don't know where the error comes

Comment: So, you've downloaded 10 images already and that works?

Comment: @NikMyers 12 images. And the images which not from AWS shows.

Comment: In AWS, are the images (and the directory they're in) set to be publicly accessible? You have to explicitly set that either when uploading to it or via the properties menu

Comment: @Guardanis Thank you so much for solving my problem~!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download images from AWS S3 bucket, you need to use AmazonS3 Client. Then using the awskey and aws secret key you can download any image using the below code.

```
   Resources res = mContext.getResources();
            String awsKey = res.getString(R.string.aws_key);
            String awsSecretKey = res.getString(R.string.aws_secret_key);
            String awsBucketName = res.getString(R.string.aws_bucket_name);
            AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                    new BasicAWSCredentials(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.aws_key),
                            mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.aws_secret_key)));

            S3ObjectInputStream content = s3Client.getObject(awsBucketName, url).getObjectContent();
```

Comment: No need to essentially use S3Client for downloading images from AWS S3. You can do this with AWS signed urls as well, as long as S3 urls are sending the correct response headers.